# Fast comparison between pyspark dataframe and a list of elements?

Tags: python, pyspark

Good Afternoon everyone! I have an issue in my project. I need to read each element of a pyspark dataframe and use each of these together another each element in a list..

This takes a lot of time 'cause the dataframe could be composed by 100 to 180k rows and the lists could be composed by 100-400 elements.. How can I speed the process? I tried to create something to speed up the process by the time is horrible:

```
# this is a function that takes a weighted score between two of the famouse distances for text similarity
def triplet_weighted_avg_score(word1, word2):
    levenshstein = fuzz.ratio(word1, word2)/100 # levenshstein distance
    s = SequenceMatcher(None); s.set_seq1(word1); s.set_seq2(word2); edit = s.ratio() # edit distance
    #jaro_ = jaro.jaro_winkler_metric(word1, word2)
    
    return 0.6*levenshstein+0.40*edit #+0.20*jaro_

# this function iterates through a dataset of comuni and check which element of the list of unigrams, bigrams and trigrams over a text is more similar, later I am appending the value
def find_comune(df, unigrams, bigrams, trigrams):
    edited_text = []
    
    for row in df.collect():
        for unigram in unigrams:
            score = triplet_weighted_avg_score(row['Comune'].lower(), unigram)
            if score > 0.90:
                edited_text.append([row['Comune'], unigram, score])
        
        for bigram in bigrams:
            score = triplet_weighted_avg_score(row['Comune'].lower(), bigram)
            if score > 0.90:
                edited_text.append([row['Comune'], bigram, score])
                
        for trigram in trigrams:
            score = triplet_weighted_avg_score(row['Comune'].lower(), trigram)
            if score > 0.90:
                edited_text.append([row['Comune'], unigram, score])
    
    return sorted(edited_text, key = lambda x: x[2])

# this function iterates through a dataset of surnames and check which element of the list of unigrams and bigrams over a text is more similar, later I am appending the value
def find_cognome(df, unigrams, bigrams):
    edited_text = []
    
    for row in df.collect():
        for unigram in unigrams:
            score = triplet_weighted_avg_score(row['Cognome'].lower(), unigram)
            if score > 0.90:
                edited_text.append([row['Cognome'], unigram, score])
        
        for bigram in bigrams:
            score = triplet_weighted_avg_score(row['Cognome'].lower(), bigram)
            if score > 0.90:
                edited_text.append([row['Cognome'], bigram, score])
    
    return sorted(edited_text, key = lambda x: x[2])

# this function iterates through a dataset of names and check which element of the list of unigrams and bigrams over a text is more similar, later I am appending the value
def find_nome(df, unigrams, bigrams):
    edited_text = []
    
    for row in df.collect():
        for unigram in unigrams:
            score = triplet_weighted_avg_score(row['Nome'].lower(), unigram)
            if score > 0.90:
                edited_text.append([row['Nome'], row['Sesso'], unigram, score])
        
        for bigram in bigrams:
            score = triplet_weighted_avg_score(row['Nome'].lower(), bigram)
            if score > 0.90:
                edited_text.append([row['Nome'], row['Sesso'], bigram, score])
    
    return sorted(edited_text, key = lambda x: x[2])
```

above there are the functions used, below the main code:

```
for column_empty in ["COMUNE_DI_RESIDENZA", "COGNOME_E_NOME"]:
    
    if df_spark_transl.first()[column_empty] == "NULL":
        if column_empty == "COMUNE_DI_RESIDENZA":
            comuni = find_comune(df_comuni, unigrams, bigrams, trigrams)
        
        if column_empty == "COGNOME_E_NOME":
            cognomi = find_cognome(df_cognomi, unigrams, bigrams)
            nomi = find_nome(df_nomi_e_sesso, unigrams, bigrams)
```

Comment: Try to put some example of the data you have and to explain what your functions do. Anyways, since the dimension of the Pyspark Dataframe is not huge (about 200k rows). I would probably transform the Pyspark dataframe into Pandas Dataframe and then work with Pandas DF (use the method "my_pyspark_df.toPandas()")

Comment: Hi! For example:

- df_comuni: takes as column "Regione" with values like -> Andria, Barletta etc.
- df_cognomi: takes as column "Cognome" with values like -> Abbasciano, Bresca etc.
- df_nomi_e_sesso: takes as columns ["Nome", "Sesso"] with values like -> Adriano M, Francesca F etc.

instead unigrams is considering the text splitted by one words, bigrams respect two words and trigrams respect three words

Comment: Try to edit the question inserting the input table and a desired output explaining what you want your functions to do, otherwise it becomes really difficult understanding which is the problem you are facing.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).